# Plot a Dictionary of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a dictionary of dataframes (Di):

```
Di = {}
groups = [2,3]
for grp in groups:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : (grp*2, grp*3, grp*4),
                       'B' : (grp*4, grp*5, grp*2)})
    Di[grp] = df
```

For each df in Di, I would like to plot A against B in a single graph.
I tried:

```
for grp in groups:
    ax1 = Di[grp].plot(x='A', y='B')
```

But that gave me two graphs:

[image]
[image]

How do I get them both in the same graph please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print on a same ax:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,8))

for grp in groups:
    Di[grp].plot(x='A', y='B',ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer that also loops round but that uses matplotlib instead of pandas:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
for grp in groups:
    ax1.plot(Di[grp]['A'], Di[grp]['B'], label=grp)
```

[image]